# All units in $Z_6[x]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Since units of $Z_6$ are $\{ 1, 5 \}$ and no other element is nilpotent so only units of $Z_6[x]$ are $\{1,5\}$

Is this explanation correct ?

Comment: Ah? What do units have to do with nilpotents and...whatever? The only units of $\;\Bbb Z_6\;$ are $\;\{1,5\}\pmod 6\;$ because they are the only ones. Period. Now, there also are no non-zero nilpotent elements in that ring (again, because there aren't. Period)...but that's completely unrelated to the units business. Another matter is if you want **to prove** these two unrelated facts, though...

Comment: @DonAntonio Actually, the nonexistance of nilpotent elements is relevant. consider the polynomial $2x-1$ in $\mathbb{Z}_4$. It is a unit, since $(2x-1)(2x+1)=1$. This happens because $2$ is nilpotent in $\mathbb{Z}_4$.

Comment: @DonAntonio I also missed the $[x]$ in $\Bbb Z_6[x]$ the first time I read the question.

Comment: @Arthur Me too...and now idok's comment is more relevant! I guess that was due to the fact the original post was written without MathJaX ...

Comment: The explanation is correct pending a proof that f(x) in A[x] is a unit if(f) its constant term is a unit and all other coefficients are nilpotent. (this is true; it is exercise 2i from chapter 1 of AM , the hint to which is essentially the solution)